# Url Rewrite in a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, restler

I'm using Restler for building REST API on an Apache Server and I have some url rewrite problems.
Here are my directories :

**/api:**
  /vendor
  ...
  **.htaccess (1st level)**
  **/public :**
    /examples
    /test
    /src
    **.htaccess (2nd level)**
    **/explorer :**
      /css
      /images
      /lib
      index.html

Now, here is what I want :
1) I want an invisible "public" directory from the others. 
For example  a request like **GET mydomain.com/api/data** will pick it directly into **mydomain.com/api/public/data**
2) I want the root of "public" directory to be **explorer/index.html** but this file load a lot of resources in a relative way and sometimes it don't load.

So basically I want to access to /api/public/explorer/index.html with all the resources loaded if I only try to access to : **mydomain.com/api**

Here is what I have now :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/public/$1
```

For the first-level .htaccess, which seems to works pretty well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/$ explorer/ [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

For the second-level .htaccess

Any recommandations ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ explorer/ [QSA,L]
```

Isn't going to work, because requests that reach that rule will have the leading slash stripped off:

```
RewriteRule ^$ explorer/ [QSA,L]
```

But I'm not exactly sure that's what you want either, because in order to get to that rule, you'd need to go to:

```
http://mydomain.com/api/
```

If that's what you want, then you just need to remove that leading slash.

Comment: Thank you ! Just one thing left, the assets (css, images, js) are not loaded. In the chrome console for example for one js file :
http://mydomain.com/api/public/lib/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js

So it's missing the explorer/ !

Comment: Notice that i just remove the  [L,R=301] from my original post cause it was displaying the final URL, which I don't want.

Comment: @cocoggu Not sure what you can do about fixing broken links. Relative URL links and messing with removing path nodes in mod rewrite will *never* mix. You either have to fix all of your links to use a common base URL or move your assets so they are accessible using the relative URL